# why we cant draw a String using graphics object in this example

Tags: java, graphics, applet, awt, java-2d

I want to draw a string using  a init method   but if use inside start method then its work fine.
Please explain me

```
    public class Canv extends Applet //applet class 
    {   
        public void start()
        {

        }
         public void init()
        {                                     
            System.out.println("hi");
            Canvas c=new Canvas();              // want to print String in canvas

            c.setSize(500,500);
            c.setBackground(Color.red);
            add(c);
            Graphics g=c.getGraphics();  
            g.drawString("hello buddy",60,60); 
        }
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {

        }
        public void stop()
        {
            System.out.println("stop");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the code that works?

Comment: just copy paste init code into the start method then its work

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 1):

If you carefully read the API provided by Java, then you would see for `init`:

```
 * Called by the browser or applet viewer to inform
 * this applet that it has been loaded into the system. It is always
 * called before the first time that the <code>start</code> method is
 * called.
 * <p>
 * A subclass of <code>Applet</code> should override this method if
 * it has initialization to perform. For example, an applet with
 * threads would use the <code>init</code> method to create the
 * threads and the <code>destroy</code> method to kill them.
```

And for `start`:

```
 * Called by the browser or applet viewer to inform
 * this applet that it should start its execution. It is called after
 * the <code>init</code> method and each time the applet is revisited
 * in a Web page.
```

Obviously, the code that uses this interface to manipulate Java applets does not show the canvas written in the `init()` method because the UI at that point is not ready. It's just a marker for you that the container started initializing your app.

Comment: but my canvas is printed in this case and g.drawString("hello buddy",60,60); is not printed here